# When did Jack O'Neill kill this character?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

I'm currently reading *The Cost of Honor* by Sally Malcolm, one of the Fandemonium published novels based on *Stargate SG-1*. Several times in the narrative, Col. Jack O'Neill's internal voice reminds him of a time when he killed Major Samantha Carter (allegedly "To save her").

It's been a few years since I watched *SG-1* and I can't remember that happening. What is the book referring to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like this is a reference to [SG1: Entity](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Entity_(episode)). Sam was taken over by a space-virus thingy and Jack zats her twice (something that should otherwise kill her) to stop her from damaging the facility.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Possibly 4.20 'Entity'. An alien consciousness takes over Sam's body; O'Neill shoots her twice. No detectable brain activity, but they manage to restore her mind from a computer.

https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Entity_(episode)